# I need a google sheets cell formula to display every time a value occurs over multiple rows and columns

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a grid of a calendar month, dates on the top row and times of day along the left column.  I need a cell formula that will list the days of every instances of a value.  For instance, if "Name 1" appears on the 1st, 3rd and 5th of January, the cell would indicate, "January 1,3,5".  An example of what I'm trying to created should be linked.  (This is my first question to Stackoverflow, so apologies if formatting is wrong.)

[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11LVhLjZHQC09yBY19ebf-_01mYdNhfZea_lZ_TYPraQ/edit?usp=sharing)

I actually got something to work, but it's incredibly long, requires helper columns, and will be an absolute huge pain in the future as I'm planning on creating a schedule that spans literal years.  I'd like it to be as simple as possible.

My current formulas include COUNTIFS and a convoluted way of creating commas between the numbers. (Which is my main issue.)  I'm guessing something like an ARRAYFORUMLA maybe combined with a FILTER and TEXTJOIN would do it much more easily, but I can't figure out how.  Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: `as I'm planning on creating a schedule that spans literal years` If so how does the expected output look like if input data comprises of multiple months + years per se.,

Answer (score 1):

The initial answer by Lerato wasn't exactly right, but without it, I never would have figured it out, so thank you so much, Lerato!

This did the trick:

=(TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE,(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(if(search("NAME 1",$B$2:$K$18),TEXT($B$1, "MMM "), "")),"")))))))&(TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE,(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(if(search("NAME 1",$B$2:$K$18),TEXT($B$1:K1, "D"), "")),"")))))))

Edited to update.  My initial formula I thought worked, but I realized it sorted numbers alphabetically, so they're appear, "1,10,2,3", etc. Removing SORT and adding TRANSPOSE fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this formula: =TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, IF($B$2:$ZZ$100="Name 1", TEXT($B$1:$ZZ$1, "mm d"), "")) ?

Comment: No I hadn't, and thank you for your response!  But unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.  It says, "A matching value could not be found. To get values for the entire range use the ARRAYFORMULA function."

Comment: Update:  Haven't solved it yet, but I was able to add Arrayformula to get it to output something.  Using, "=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, (ARRAYFORMULA(IF($B$2:$I$18="Name 1", TEXT($B$1:$I$1, "d"), ""))) )" it now displays, "1,2,4,1,8,1,6,4".  I'm trying SORT and UNIQUE, but I'm not having any luck.  Also not sure how to add the month up top.  I can make it so it says, "Jan 1, Jan 2", but I'm trying to only have it once up top.